SATA partially failing after 24.04 upgrade
I have a small/cheap home NAS build I use for backups and other bulk storage. It has a SATA card with 8 ports to connect 8 drives. The card uses a ASM1064 chipset and a JB575 port multiplier.
After upgrading to 24.04 server only 4 of the 8 ports on the card function.
When I attach a disk to one of non working ports, I get the message:
[ 1254.035054] DMAR: DRHD: handling fault status reg 2
[ 1254.035087] DMAR: [DMA Write NO_PASID] Request device [01:00.0] fault addr 0x66f6c000 [fault reason 0x05] PTE Write access is not set

If I boot into a 23.10 live CD all 8 ports work.
lspci -k
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Gemini Lake Host Bridge (rev 06)
    DeviceName: Onboard - Other
    Subsystem: ASRock Incorporation Gemini Lake Host Bridge
00:00.1 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Celeron/Pentium Silver Processor Dynamic Platform and Thermal Framework Processor Participant (rev 06)
    DeviceName: Onboard - Other
    Subsystem: ASRock Incorporation Celeron/Pentium Silver Processor Dynamic Platform and Thermal Framework Processor Participant
    Kernel driver in use: proc_thermal
    Kernel modules: processor_thermal_device_pci_legacy
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation GeminiLake [UHD Graphics 605] (rev 06)
    DeviceName: Onboard - Video
    Subsystem: ASRock Incorporation GeminiLake [UHD Graphics 605]
    Kernel driver in use: i915
    Kernel modules: i915
00:0f.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Celeron/Pentium Silver Processor Trusted Execution Engine Interface (rev 06)
    DeviceName: Onboard - Other
    Subsystem: ASRock Incorporation Celeron/Pentium Silver Processor Trusted Execution Engine Interface
    Kernel driver in use: mei_me
    Kernel modules: mei_me
00:12.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Celeron/Pentium Silver Processor SATA Controller (rev 06)
    DeviceName: Onboard - SATA
    Subsystem: ASRock Incorporation Celeron/Pentium Silver Processor SATA Controller
    Kernel driver in use: ahci
    Kernel modules: ahci
00:13.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Gemini Lake PCI Express Root Port (rev f6)
    Subsystem: ASRock Incorporation Gemini Lake PCI Express Root Port
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
00:13.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Gemini Lake PCI Express Root Port (rev f6)
    Subsystem: ASRock Incorporation Gemini Lake PCI Express Root Port
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
00:13.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Gemini Lake PCI Express Root Port (rev f6)
    Subsystem: ASRock Incorporation Gemini Lake PCI Express Root Port
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
00:13.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Gemini Lake PCI Express Root Port (rev f6)
    Subsystem: ASRock Incorporation Gemini Lake PCI Express Root Port
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
00:15.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Celeron/Pentium Silver Processor USB 3.0 xHCI Controller (rev 06)
    DeviceName: Onboard - Other
    Subsystem: ASRock Incorporation Celeron/Pentium Silver Processor USB 3.0 xHCI Controller
    Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd
    Kernel modules: xhci_pci
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Celeron/Pentium Silver Processor LPC Controller (rev 06)
    DeviceName: Onboard - Other
    Subsystem: ASRock Incorporation Celeron/Pentium Silver Processor LPC Controller
00:1f.1 SMBus: Intel Corporation Celeron/Pentium Silver Processor Gaussian Mixture Model (rev 06)
    DeviceName: Onboard - Other
    Subsystem: ASRock Incorporation Celeron/Pentium Silver Processor Gaussian Mixture Model
    Kernel driver in use: i801_smbus
    Kernel modules: i2c_i801
01:00.0 SATA controller: ASMedia Technology Inc. ASM1064 Serial ATA Controller (rev 02)
    Subsystem: ZyDAS Technology Corp. Device 2116
    Kernel driver in use: ahci
    Kernel modules: ahci
03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8211/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 15)
    DeviceName: Onboard - RTK Ethernet
    Subsystem: ASRock Incorporation Motherboard (one of many)
    Kernel driver in use: r8169
    Kernel modules: r8169
04:00.0 SATA controller: ASMedia Technology Inc. ASM1061/ASM1062 Serial ATA Controller (rev 02)
    Subsystem: ASRock Incorporation Motherboard
    Kernel driver in use: ahci
    Kernel modules: ahci

